# Copying object inside the initialization list

Tags: c++

How to change `Axes (Axes const &crAxes) { *this = crAxes; }` into `Axes (Axes const &crAxes) : (*this)(crAxes) {}`, so to copy the object inside the initialization list (before X, Y, and Z are initialized to their default value).

Changing form this:

```
struct Axes
{
    Axes () : X(0.f), Y(0.f), Z(0.f) {}
    Axes (Axes const &crAxes) { *this = crAxes; }

    float   X;
    float   Y;
    float   Z;

};
```

Into something like this:

```
struct Axes
{

    Axes () : X(0.f), Y(0.f), Z(0.f) {}
    Axes (Axes const &crAxes) : (*this)(crAxes) {}

    float   X;
    float   Y;
    float   Z;

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do such thing in copy c-tor.
Use simply

```
Axes(const Axes& rhs) : X(rhs.X), Y(rhs.Y), Z(rhs.Z) {}
```

However, there is no need in copy c-tor here, since default-implemented copy c-tor will do same things (`memberwise-copy`).

Comment: Just finished researching about `Memberwise Copy` and also `Shallow Copy ,Deep Copy, Bitwise copy`. Thank you for the hints. ^^